# How can I change the package type when calling a method?

Tags: go

I have this package in Go

```
package dao

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Product struct {
    Name      string
    Price     string
    SalePrice string
    ID        string
    URL       string
}

var products []Product

func New(name string, price string, saleprice string, url string, id string) *Product {
    return &Product{
        Name:      name,
        Price:     price,
        SalePrice: saleprice,
        URL:       url,
        ID:        id,
    }
}

func (p *Product) Add() {
    products = append(products, p)
}
```

But when I use it in my main.go, located at the root level, I cannot call `p.Add()` like this

```
p := dao.New("hello", "10", "20", "http", "id")
p.Add()
```

The error I am getting is this `cannot use p (type *Product) as type Product in append` and when I check the type inside the Product.Add() I get `*dao.Product`.

Inside main the type is product.Product and not product. The type is different. How do I manage this?

Comment: your `products` type is slice of `Product`, not `*Product`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to append pointer to struct to the slice of Product not slice of *Product. Quick solution would be to change

```
var products []Product
```

into

```
var products []*Product
```